# solidity - supportsInterface with ERC165 in the abstract contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I have an abstract contract.

```js
abstract contract Test is ERC165 {
   
   function great1() public {

   }

   function great2() public {

   }

   function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override returns(bool) {
     return interfaceId == type(Test).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
   }

}
```

Problem with this is `supportsInterface` gets included in the `Test`'s interfaceId which is wrong.. but I also don't want do the following, because doing `XOR` by `^` each time is horrible if there're more than 10 functions inside `Test`.

```
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override returns(bool) {
     return interfaceId == this.great1.selector ^ this.great2.selector || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
   }
```

Wha't the right way of doing this ? maybe I shouldn't be doing supportsInterface in the abstract contracts ever and directly do it in the final, most inherited one ?